# Shorthand if else with razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im using this in my view and want it to display only "Yes" or "No"
but its displaying `False?"yes":"No"`

```
@myPosts.Contains(item.ID)?"Yes":"No"
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: Here is another set of answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091831/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-razor-specifically-on-html-attributes

Comment: For your perusal: The brains behind razor syntax. This is very likely everything you ever wanted to know about razor and more: http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Andrew-Nurse-Inside-Razor/

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You need parentheses to use an expression:

```
@(myPosts.Contains(item.ID)?"Yes":"No")
```

Answer (score 11):

You can even nest shorthand if inside of another shorthand if!

```
@(myPosts != null ? (myPosts.Contains(item.ID) ? "Yes" : "No") : "Null")
```

Comment: which is kind of use full when it comes to nullables: `@(myObject.NullableBool != null ? (myObject.NullableBool ? "Yes" : "No") : "What would I know..")`