# Razor If/Else conditional operator syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Not having much luck, I have the following if/else statement in Razor which works perfectly

```
<small>
  @if(deletedView){
     @:Deleted
  } 
  else {
     @:Created
  } by
</small>
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<small>
  @(deletedView) ? @:Deleted : @:Created by
</small>
```

But that fails miserably. What is the proper syntax?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091831/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-razor-specifically-on-html-attributes

Comment: mmhh, can't close my own question.

Comment: For people wanting to open/close tags conditionally, this will be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24385375/9725841

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You need to put the entire ternary expression in parenthesis.  Unfortunately that means you can't use "@:", but you could do something like this:

```
@(deletedView ? "Deleted" : "Created by")
```

Razor currently supports a subset of C# expressions without using @() and unfortunately, ternary operators are not part of that set.

Comment: @David Lively already answered by thanks :) At least can "close" the question now...

Comment: +1 for 'Razor currently supports a subset of C# expressions without using @()' was wondering why @if (condition) { was giving me an error

Comment: @Andrew Nurse, As per you have mentioned, "Razor currently supports a subset of C# expressions without using @() and unfortunately, ternary operators are not part of that set". I would like to know what all operators are part of that set? Thanks!

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30151780/2218697) for else if in razor