# ASP.NET MVC 3 using Razor - use conditional expression together with the HTML output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've been bugged with this for many days...(I'm in process of studying ASP.NET MVC 3)

In this link -- [Razor If/Else conditional operator syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607843/razor-if-else-conditional-operator-syntax) -- is said that the only valid syntax for conditional expression in Razor engine is @(x?y:z)

Alright. Now, how do I write HTML in this conditional expression? I can't use Razor here, following code results in invalid syntax error.

```
@(item.Manager == null ? @:<i>unassigned</i> : item.Manager.Name)
```

After some research I discovered HtmlWriter or Html.Raw but neither of them, nor their methods .toString() or .toHtmlString() help because they are not of string but of IHtmlString type.

Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
@(item.Manager == null ? new HtmlString("<i>unassigned</i>") : new HtmlString( item.Manager.Name) )
```