# ASP.NET WebApp How to change nav bar "Login" to "Logged in"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Hey guys so I've been looking online and i just cant figure this out..

I've used the Visual studio base Web app essentially as a skeleton to start my web app and i have this in "Site.Master" which i think is the class holding everything about the Navigation page:

```
   "<li><a runat="server" id= "liLogin" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a>
   </li>"
```

I want to change this name "Log in" To Logged in as a result of an if statement

But: i don't know how to call it...

thanks!

Comment: How do you authenticate user?

Comment: When any page loads, i have an if statement which checks if Session["user"] is empty or filled. thats when the website knows if the user is logged in for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762537/asp-net-mvc-3-using-razor-use-conditional-expression-together-with-the-html-ou

Answer (score 1):

```
   <li><a runat="server" id= "liLogin" href="~/Account/Login">
 @if(User.IsAuthenticated)
{
   <text>Logged In</text>
}
else
{
<text>Log In</text>
}
</a>
   </li>
```

Comment: if he is using Razor

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/849113/Four-Easy-Steps-to-Set-Up-OWIN-for-Form-authentica