# Razor syntax in Menu

Tags: razor

I am building a menu with Razor and having a problem with it displaying properly. Here is the line that is giving me problems:

```
<li @topNavCurrentCount == @topNavCount ? "class=last" : @string.Empty><a href="@node.Url.Replace("~/","/").Replace(".aspx","")">@node.Title</a>
```

It renders the HTML like this:

```
 <li {1 == 7 ? "class=last" : ;}><a href="/Home">Home</a>
```

I know im close to getting it but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try placing brackets around the if statement.

```
<li @(topNavCurrentCount == topNavCount ? "class=last" : string.Empty)>
```

@ next to a variable will print the value

Answer (score 1):

I think the following might work (placing brackets around the statement):

```
<li @( topNavCurrentCount == topNavCount ? "class=last" : string.Empty)><a href="@node.Url.Replace("~/","/").Replace(".aspx","")">@node.Title</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your logical expression with an `@()`. What's currently going on is that only your variable's values are being sent to the view.

See:
[Razor If/Else conditional operator syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607843/razor-if-else-conditional-operator-syntax)