# How do I conditionally output HTML with Razor syntax?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

What I'm trying to do is simple:

```
<td class="bold-and-caps">@{if (++i == 1) { subsec.Title } else { String.Empty } } </td>
```

except I'm getting

> "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement"

on `subsec.Title` and `String.Empty`.

How am I supposed to write "If condition, output X" type statements in Razor?

Comment: Correct syntax of `@if` is shown in linked [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607843/razor-if-else-conditional-operator-syntax) as well as alternative conditional operator syntax.

Answer (score 10):

You can use ternary operator for it like:

```
<td class="bold-and-caps">@( (++i == 1) ? subsec.Title : String.Empty)</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by code like this:

```
<td class="bold-and-caps">
    @if (++i == 1)
        { @subsec.Title }
    else
        { <text>@string.Empty</text> }
</td>
```

But in your case you don't have to use else with empty string when you want only display something if...

```
<td class="bold-and-caps">@if(++i == 1){ @subsec.Title }<td>
```

Comment: This is absolutely the same invalid code as provided in the question. Explanation why do you believe is different could help.

Comment: Not the same, but was invalid, I've fixed it :)