# ASP.NET MVC Razor Ternary with HTML.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ternary-operator

I am trying to do the answer to this:

[How to use ternary operator in razor (specifically on HTML attributes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091831/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-razor-specifically-on-html-attributes)

With a Html.ActionLink; something like this:

```
@(ViewData["page"] == "Page1" ? "Page1" : Html.ActionLink("Page 1", "Page1", "Index"))
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ternary operation must return the same type from both halves.
You're returning a `String` on the left, but an `IHtmlString` on the right.

Change it to

```
@(ViewData["page"] == "Page1" ? Html.Raw("Page1") : Html.ActionLink(...))
```

You may also want to move this into an HTML helper extension method.