# Ternary Operator in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use ternary operator in razor (specifically on HTML attributes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091831/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-razor-specifically-on-html-attributes)

I am trying to do the following but its erroring so I'm obviously doing something wrong with the Razor syntax:

```
<td>@{item.Licence.MachineId != null ? @:"TB Master" : @:"HandHeld"}  </td>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729024/asp-net-mvc-razor-ternary

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<td>@(item.Licence.MachineId != null ? "TB Master" : "HandHeld")</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<td>@(item.Licence.MachineId != null ? "TB Master" : "HandHeld")</td>
```