# ASP.NET MVC Razor: Ternary

Tags: asp.net, view, razor

Having a little bit of trouble figuring out using a ternary with Razor view engine.

My model has a string property. If that string property is null, I want to render `null` in the view. If the property is not null, I want it to render the property value with a leading and trailing `'`.

How can I do this?

UPDATE: Sorry, changed question slightly.

Comment: Can you use the null coalescing opererator? Something like: @Model.MyString ?? "'null'"

Comment: I'm agree with @Darin Dimitrov. *Ternary, loops, C# and stuff makes views ugly.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should just be able to use a ternary operator like the title suggests:

```
@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Prop) ? "null" : "'" + Model.Prop + "'")
```

Comment: Perfect! I was using a '{}' instead of '()'!

Answer (score 6):

Assume you have an entity named `Test` with the `First` and `Last` properties:

```
public class Test {

    public string First { get; set; }

    public string Last { get; set; }
}
```

You can use `DisplayFormat.DataFormatString` and `DisplayFormat.NullDisplayText` to achieve your purpose:

```
public class Test {

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "'{0}'", NullDisplayText = "'null'")]
    public string First { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "'{0}'", NullDisplayText = "'null'")]
    public string Last { get; set; }
}
```

AND in view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.First)

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Last)
```

**I change the answer too:**

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "'{0}'", NullDisplayText = "null")]
```

Answer (score 4):

Ternary, loops, C# and stuff makes views ugly.

That's what view models are exactly designed to do:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "null", DataFormatString = "'{0}'"]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your strongly typed view simply:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyProperty)
```