# How to get the Null Coalesce operator to work in ASP.NET MVC Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, null-coalescing-operator

I have the following, but it's failing with a `NullReferenceException`:

```
<td>@item.FundPerformance.Where(xx => fund.Id == xx.Id).FirstOrDefault().OneMonth ?? -</td>
```

`OneMonth` is defined as

```
public virtual decimal? OneMonth { get; set; }
```

and its value is null at the time that it fails.

I thought the Null Coalesce operator would test if its null and if so, return the value to the right of the operator?

What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `FundPerformance`-object selected by `FirstOrDefault()` that is null? If that's the case than you'd be trying to get a reference from an object that is null, which gives a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: I reckon Joakim is right.  Also, you should really be doing this calculation in a ViewModel and just passing the answer into your razor view.  And if you are actually doing a database lookup from your view then that's very naughty! :-)

Comment: Hi guys. It turns out your both correct. I did a dumb. Just to alleviate any concerns, I promise I'm not doing the database call from the View! The ViewModel is populated in the Controller via a Service call to the Repository.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729024/asp-net-mvc-razor-ternary

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The razor syntax, as you wrote it, ends at "OneMonth". The ?? are interpreted as text. To have it interpreted as razor, you must wrap the whole statements in () like this:

```
<td>@(item.FundPerformance.Where(xx => fund.Id == xx.Id).FirstOrDefault().OneMonth ?? "-")</td>
```

This will still get you an error: the left operator is a decimal and the right operator is a string. So you can either render a zero instead of "-" or use ternary operator, with OneMonth.Value.ToString() as left value and "-" as right value.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to do with MVC or Razor.

```
FundPerformance.Where(xx => fund.Id == xx.Id).FirstOrDefault()
```

will return null if there is no element that matches, null does not have a OneMonth porperty so you will get a null ref exception.  You cannot use the ?? operator as it is not OneMonth that is null, it is the result of `FirstOrDefault()`.

To test change your code to

```
FundPerformance.Where(xx => fund.Id == xx.Id).First().OneMonth ?? -</td>
```

If you get a "sequence contains no elements" exception instead then you know that is your problem.

Comment: This was my issue, which can be fixed using the null-conditional operator (`?`) in addition to the null-coalescing operator (`??`). `string emptyIfNull = possiblyNullObject?.PossiblyNullProperty ?? "";`