# .NET razor show custom text if model is null

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

Say I have the following models:

```
public class Parent : BaseEntity
{
    public Child? Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child: BaseEntity
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

and I send the Parent model to my view:

```
@model Parent
```

**I would like to show a custom child name if the child is null. How can I do that in 1 line similar to following?**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="@Model.Child?.Name ?? DefaultName">
```

Comment: `"@Model.Child?.Name ?? DefaultName"` (BTW, you don't need `string?`, `string` is fine, the same goes for `Child?`, because it's a reference type.)

Comment: I think I'm missing something. It's not working. :/ Btw with .NET6 string became a nullable type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here:

[How to get the Null Coalesce operator to work in ASP.NET MVC Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444248/how-to-get-the-null-coalesce-operator-to-work-in-asp-net-mvc-razor)

The statement should be wrapped between () like following:

```
<input type="text" placeholder=@(Model.Child?.Name ?? "DefaultName")>
```