# asp.net mvc 3 User.IsInRole("Admin")

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a site with links throughout it for performing actions. Some need to be hidden if the user is not in the admin role. I am doing checking on the backend just in case someone types i n the url directly etc. but is it enough to have this in the razor view?

```
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Items</li>
@if(User.IsInRole("Admin"){
    <li>Users</li>
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, that is sufficient.

Or as I found in another post which i used lately:

```
public static MvcHtmlString If(this MvcHtmlString value, bool evaluation)
{
     return evaluation ? value : MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

so you can use this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create").If(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
```

However, if you are using links to other pages which you need to prevent from accessing when not in a specific role. You should also include the Authorize attribute in the controllers you want to prevent them from accessing:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any change of providing a link to that 'other post'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981853/asp-net-mvc3-razor-display-actionlink-based-on-user-role there it is!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Also add attribute to respective method in your controller to prevent manual calls

```
[Authorize( Roles = "Admin" )]
```