# Ignore @Html.Action() if user not in Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes

In my **View** i render menu `@Html.Action("RenderMenu", "Admin")` and `@Html.Action("RenderMenu", "Manager")` 
Where Action:

> ```
>     [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
>     public ActionResult RenderMenu()
>     {
>         return View();
>     }
> ```

If user not in Role **Admin**

> `@Html.Action("RenderMenu", "Admin")` just ignore.

how can I do it?
Now, i have infinite login window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer 
[Asp.net MVC3: is really based on roles @Html.Action()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303162/asp-net-mvc3-is-really-based-on-roles-html-action/20303267#20303267)

you can get it using:

```
@Html.ActionBaseRole("RenderMenu", "Admin")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make if in razor view to check if user is in needed role. You could use (User.IsInRole("Adm inistrators"))

There was similar discussion here [asp.net MVC3 razor: display actionlink based on user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981853/asp-net-mvc3-razor-display-actionlink-based-on-user-role)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
@if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin")) {   
    @Html.Action("RenderMenu", "Admin")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a answer. You may try it ......

```
@{
    if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
       {
          @Html.Action("RenderMenu", "Admin")
          @Html.Action("RenderMenu", "Manager")
       }
   else
      {
@Html.Action("RenderMenu", "Manager")

     }
}
```