# How to check for logged-in user ASP in HTML?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I need to hide a link if a user is not logged in, and show the link if the user is logged in. I should use HTML. But the following:

```
 @if(Authorize(Roles = "admin")) <li>@Html.ActionLink(@Resources.LayoutLang.myarticles, "MyReviews", "Review")</li>
```

does not work. How to check the role in HTML?

Comment: `@(if (User.IsInRole("admin")) { <li>....</li> }`

Comment: Take a look at this answer it should help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981853/asp-net-mvc3-razor-display-actionlink-based-on-user-role/6981928#6981928

Comment: Error - Role Manager feature is not included. But this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Reviewer"); in controller is work

Comment: What is `Authorizer`? Is this some kind of authorization service?

Comment: I don't remember where find this)))

Comment: "Role manager featured is not included" i fix added string in web.config. I have new problem - if user logged in, page is not load.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check that the user is signed in:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsInRole`

```
  @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {
         <li>@Html.ActionLink(@Resources.LayoutLang.myarticles, "MyReviews", "Review")</li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li>Not logged in</li>
    }
```