# Can I write an inline if with HTML content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, inline-if

I want to write something like:

```
@( checkCondition ? "<span class='label'>Right!</span>" : "")
```

But it is showing the source code instead the HTML, there is a easy way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091831/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-razor-specifically-on-html-attributes

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use `@Html.Raw(mystring)` method like this:

```
@( checkCondition ? Html.Raw("<span class='label'>Right!</span>") : Html.Raw(""))
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried but I get error implicit conversion between'System.Web.IHtmlString' and 'string', seems that I have to use the standar If for this case.

Comment: Use `Raw` method for both strings as above. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 26):

You can be even more concise (granted harder to read) with this:

```
@Html.Raw(checkCondition ? "<span class='label'>Right!</span>": string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also do like that:

```
@if (checkCondition ) { <text><span class='label'>Right!</span></text> }
```

The text tag allows you to write html with syntax highlighting!