# Condition in a class in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How to have a condition work in razor, I have the code below, but it didn't work.

```
<span id="tab1" class="@TempData["CurrentTab"] == 'tab1' ? 'ListTag ActiveTag' : 'ListTag'">@MyAccountRes.VTxt_BasicInformation</span>                        
<span id="tab2" class="@TempData["CurrentTab"] == 'tab2' ? 'ListTag ActiveTag' : 'ListTag'">@MyAccountRes.VTxt_DetailInformation</span>
<span id="tab3" class="@TempData["CurrentTab"] == 'tab3' ? 'ListTag ActiveTag' : 'ListTag'">@MyAccountRes.VTxt_IconManagment</span>
<span id="tab4" class="@TempData["CurrentTab"] == 'tab4' ? 'ListTag ActiveTag' : 'ListTag'">@MyAccountRes.VTxt_EducationInfomation</span>
<span id="tab5" class="@TempData["CurrentTab"] == 'tab5' ? 'ListTag ActiveTag' : 'ListTag'">@MyAccountRes.VTxt_JobInfomation</span>
```

What is the correct syntax?

Thanks

Rj

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ternary operator in razor (specifically on HTML attributes)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091831/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-razor-specifically-on-html-attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<span id="tab1" class="@(TempData["CurrentTab"] == "tab1" ? "ListTag ActiveTag" : "ListTag")">@MyAccountRes.VTxt_BasicInformation</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing some parentheses:

```
<span id="tab1" class="@(TempData["CurrentTab"] == "tab1" ? "ListTag ActiveTag" : "ListTag")">@MyAccountRes.VTxt_BasicInformation</span>
```