# check model value empty or null in javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ternary-operator, isnullorempty

This is my code

```
 <script>
 var _getValue = @myViewModel.myInfo.Name == null ? 'isNull' : 'notNull';
 </script>
```

The value `@myViewModel.myInfo.Name` is null in database , but this code always return `notNull` .
How can I properly check empty or null for that ?

Comment: Did you try to debug it? What value does the property hold when you inspect it in debugging session?

Comment: yes, when I debug , `@myViewModel.myInfo.Name` is null .
But It's weird , when I check like `'@myViewModel.myInfo.Name' == '' ? 'isNull' : 'notNull'` , it return `isNull` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add it in braces with a `@` symbol

e.g.

```
<script>
    var _getValue = '@(myViewModel.myInfo.Name == null ? "isNull" : "notNull")';
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what happens when Razor and javascript are mixed a lot, so don't fall into habit of doing that often!

Consider this line:

```
 <script>
 var _getValue = @myViewModel.myInfo.Name == null ? 'isNull' : 'notNull';
 </script>
```

The only server-side Razor piece here is `@myViewModel.myInfo.Name`, which returns null, which is rendered as an empty string. So what is going to client is:

```
 <script>
 var _getValue = '' == null ? 'isNull' : 'notNull';
 </script>
```

This is pure js now, and it is executed on the client side, and naturally gives 'notNull'. After all, empty string is not null indeed.

Now consider this:

```
 <script>
 var _getValue = '@myViewModel.myInfo.Name' == '' ? 'isNull' : 'notNull';
 </script>
```

Razor piece is still the same, `@myViewModel.myInfo.Name`, still null, so what goes to client is:

```
 <script>
 var _getValue = '' == '' ? 'isNull' : 'notNull';
 </script>
```

This time equality actually holds, and so what you get is 'isNull'.

To fix this quickly, just follow the generic syntax to [evaluate expressions in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4091831/728795):

```
 <script>
 var _getValue = '@(myViewModel.myInfo.Name == null ? "isNull" : "notNull")';
 </script>
```

Now the whole ternary thing is going to be evaluated server-side.

Going forward you might want to check out String methods [IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) and [IsNullOrWhitespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: plus one for this answer too . As @Nitin said , it should be added in braces `'@(myViewModel.myInfo.Name == null ? "isNull" : "notNull")'` .