# How to using escape quotes in cshtml

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to escape quotes inside .cshtml file. I using razor mvc. I using If inside foreach

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    <div @(i == 1 ? "class=\"tab-pane active\"" : "class=tab-pane")>
    </div>
}
```

I using slash to escape quote but not working well.

The result `<div class="&quot;tab-pane" active&quot;=""></div>`

I want the result if for 1 will be `<div class="tab-pane active"></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use ternary operator inside the `class` attribute, no need to repeat it twice:

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    <div class="@(i == 1 ? "tab-pane active" : "tab-pane")">
    </div>
}
```

Reference: [How to use ternary operator in razor (specifically on HTML attributes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091831/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-razor-specifically-on-html-attributes)

Comment: Except for cases when you then don't assign a class and you have an (illegal) `class` in your tag.

Answer (score 2):

You really should just insert/print/encode what you need, and not try to escape everything.  Also less code, you don't have to repeat classes.. nice and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
  var active = i == 1 ? "active" : string.Empty;
  <div class="tab-pane @active">
  </div>
}
```

And it's much more readable and maintainable.

Output:

```
  <div class="tab-pane active">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane ">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane ">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane ">
  </div>
```